# Why does passing an array element print 1 instead of the string I passed?

Tags: arrays, perl, parameters

If I do:

```
foreach my $comp (@compList){
  print $comp .= "\n";
  @component_dirs = DoStuff($comp); 
}
```

My output is simply:

```
String1
String2
String3
...
```

However, once I get into the method `DoStuff()`, I do:

```
sub DoStuff{
  my $strComponentName = @_;
  print "\t$strComponentName\n";
}
```

With this, my output becomes

```
String1
        1
String2
        1
String3
        1
...
```

Why?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2126365

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the array `@_` to a scalar `$strComponentName`.

In scalar context, the result of an array is the number of elements in the array.

In your case it's 1, because you call `DoStuff` with one parameter.

To actually get the parameter, you would have to write

```
my ($strComponentName) = @_;
```

This will assign an array to an array, where the first variable in the left array will contain the first element of the right array.

Answer (score 3):

To capture the elements of the array `@_`, your left hand side must be a list:

```
sub DoStuff{
  my ($strComponentName) = @_;
```

Otherwise, the array is evaluated in a [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) context and will just return the element count.

The other alternative is to specify the specific element you want in your assignment.

```
  my $strComponentName = $_[0];
```

Or [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) the first element off the array

```
  my $strComponentName = shift;
```