# Perl: Difference between ($num) and $num

Tags: regex, perl, regex-group

can someone please explain to me why this is diff:

```
my $num = '>33*1311875297587*eval*0*frame[0]*"A"<' =~ /(\d{3,})/;
> $num = 1
my ($num) = '>33*1311875297587*eval*0*frame[0]*"A"<' =~ /(\d{3,})/;
> $num = 1311875297587
```

I'm super curious to see what shenanigans are waiting for me.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126365/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Perl, parentheses usually just alters precedence. (e.g. `3+4*5` vs `(3+4)*5`)

The exception is when parentheses are found on the left-hand side (LHS) of an assignment operator. In that situation, it influences which of Perl's two assignment operators will be used.

If the LHS of an assignment is some kind of aggregate, the list assignment is used. Otherwise, the scalar assignment is used. The following are considered to be aggregates:

- `(...)` (any expression in parens)
- `@array` and `@array[...]`
- `%hash` and `@hash{...}`
- `my (...)`, `our (...)` and `local (...)` (`state (...)` throws an error.)

See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) for the differences between the two operators.

In your case, the relevant difference is the context in which the right-hand side (RHS) of the assignment is evaluated.

- The scalar assignment evaluates its RHS operand in scalar context. In scalar context, the match operator returns a boolean value indicating success or failure.
- The list assignment evaluates its RHS operand in list context.  In list context, the match operator returns the strings it captured (or `1` if the match was successful and pattern contains no captures).

Comment: can I think as a type of casting?

Comment: It doesn't change the type of any value. It's operator selection.

Comment: I'm selecting the output of the expression?

Comment: You're selecting which of the two assignment operators to use. This has effects on the context in which the assignment's operands are evaluated, and on the value returned by the assignment operator.

Comment: Thanks! since I'm here with a true master of Perl; when Perl generates those variables like $1, $2 or $_ or @_ what's the name for this programming strategy or what's the name for those variables?

Comment: "Punctuation variables". The variables set by Perl (punctuation or otherwise) are documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

Comment: thaks a lot! really helpful! I wish I could give you more points