# Subroutine not returning correct integer

Tags: perl, subroutine

I am passing data to a subroutine, but the subroutine is not returning the correct value.

```
test(5);

sub test {
    my $t = @_;
    return $t;
}
```

It should return `5` but is returning `2`.  I am using Mojolicious, but I am assuming that should not make a difference because it is just a function?

Comment: In this precise example, the result is `1` and not `2`, right?

Comment: Your subroutine will return the *number of parameters*. In this case that's `1`, not `2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126365/whats-the-difference-between-my-variablename-and-my-variablename-in-perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`my $t = @_` evaluates the array `@_` in *scalar context*, and so sets `$t` to the size of `@_`.

From [`perldoc perldata`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values)

> If you evaluate an array in scalar context, it returns the length of the array.

When you call `test(5)`, `@_` contains just `(5)`, and so its length is 1. Using Mojolicious, you might be using a *method call* which also passes the package name or object reference as an additional argument of the subroutine, so your array will have a size of `2` instead of `1` as you describe.

If you want to retrieve the content of the array instead, use

```
my ($t) = @_;
```

If you're writing a method it should rather be

```
my $self = shift;
my ($t)  = @_;
```

but it depends on how the subroutine is called.

Comment: I ended up doing `my ($self,$t) =  @_;` Now the `$t` brings back my expected result.

Comment: the way you have solved shows that it has been called something like `$thing->test(5)` and this `@_` has 2 elements, as been stated before, as a method call