# perl assign reference to subroutine

Tags: perl, reference, subroutine

I use @_ in a subroutine to get a parameter which is assigned as a reference of an array, but the result dose not showing as an array reference.

My code is down below.

```
my @aar = (9,8,7,6,5);

my $ref = \@aar;

AAR($ref);

sub AAR {
   my $ref = @_;
   print "ref = $ref";
}
```

This will print 1 , not an array reference , but if I replace @_ with shift , the print result will be a reference.

can anyone explain why I can't get a reference using @_ to me ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign an array to a scalar, you're getting the size of the array. You pass one argument (a reference to an array) to `AAR`, that's why you get 1.

To get the actual parameters, place the local variable in braces:

```
sub AAR {
   my ($ref) = @_;
   print "ref = $ref\n";
}
```

This prints something like `ref = ARRAY(0x5566c89a4710)`.

You can then use the reference to access the array elements like this:

```
print join(", ", @{$ref});
```

Answer (score 8):

This is about [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) in Perl. It is a crucial aspect of the language.

An expression like

```
my $var = @ary;
```

attempts to assign an array to a scalar.

That doesn't make sense as it stands and what happens is that the right-hand side is evaluated to the number of elements of the array and *that* is assigned to `$var`.

In order to change that behavior you need to provide the "list context" to the assignment operator.<sup>†</sup>  In this case you'd do

```
my ($var) = @ary;
```

and now we have an assignment of a list (of array elements) to a list (of variables, here only `$var`), where they are assigned one for one. So here the first element of `@ary` is assigned to `$var`.  Please note that this statement plays loose with the elusive notion of the "list."

So in your case you want

```
my ($ref) = @_;
```

and the first element from `@_` is assigned to `$ref`, as needed.

Alternatively, you can remove and return the first element of `@_` using [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), in which case the scalar-context assignment is fine

```
my $ref = shift @_;
```

In this case you can also do

```
my $ref = shift;
```

since `shift` by default works on `@_`.

This is useful when you want to remove the first element of input as it's being assigned so that the remaining `@_` is well suited for further processing. It is often done in object-oriented code.

---

It is well worth pointing out that many operators and builtin facilities in Perl act differently depending on what context they are invoked in.

For some specifics, just a few examples: the regex match operator returns true/false (1/empty string) in scalar context but the actual matches in list context,<sup>‡</sup> [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir) returns a single entry in scalar context but all of them in list context, while  [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) shows a bit more distinct difference. This context-sensitive behavior is in every corner of Perl.

User level subroutines can be made to behave that way via [wantarray](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).

---

<sup>†</sup>
See [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564428/scalar-vs-list-assignment-operator)
for a detailed discussion

<sup>‡</sup>
See it [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches) and [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for instance

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Your answer makes me know the perl syntax better.

Comment: @HenryLu You are welcome.  I suggest that you read through `perldata` (first link) and then look around [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc.html) for other resources. Also see [learn.perl.org](https://learn.perl.org/)

Comment: An addendum that may be helpful to know in the long run: it is not () that creates lists, as `1, 2, 3` and `1..5` and `@foo` are all lists as long as they're in list context (for example, the arguments to a subroutine, or the list a foreach iterates over). This is just a special case: parentheses around the left side of an assignment turns it into a list assignment. And you often need parentheses around lists on the right side of an assignment just for precedence. More: http://altreus.blogspot.com/2011/08/lists-and-things-made-of-lists.html

Comment: @Grinnz  That should be helpful for the OP, and then I'd add that a "list" is an elusive notion to start with (but I didn't mean to go there for this). Also, as the LHS `()` imposes the list context on the `=` op the RHS list is copied into the LHS _list_ (um, variables in "the list").  So we do "get a list" by `()` -- very loosely (and imprecisely) speaking. Again, it is correct that a "list" can't be created by syntax (it's on the stack, and the term is related to how operators work in the given context) but this is getting into slippy semantics :)