# How to pass correctly variable to and from called function?

Tags: perl, reference

I have implemented a class called cell and trying to store a char to it.
I find that there is a problem to retrieve the char with my setter and getter.

```
#This is the detail of the class:      
package Cell;
sub new{
  my $class = shift;
  my $self = {  
    content => -1,
  };
  return bless $self, $class;
}

#This is my setter and getter  
sub setContent{
  my ($self,$ch) = @_;
  $self->{content} = $ch;
  print("stored char".$self->{content}."\n");
} 

sub getContent{
  my $self = @_;
  print("passing back char".$self->{content}."\n");
  return $self->{content};  
} 

# this is the way i used the class
my $ch = "a";
my $cell = Cell->new();
$cell->setContent($ch);     
my $testvar = $cell->getContent();
print("test start\n".$testvar);
print("test end\n");
#
```

I find that I am able to pass the char to the setter and should be stored in $self->{content}, but when trying to retrieve char using getter,  $self->{content} become empty

Answer (score 3):

The one direct error is the line in your "getter" `getContent` method:

```
my $self = @_;  # assigns number of elements in the array to $self!
```

This attempts to assign an array to a scalar, what doesn't make sense as it stands. What is done instead is that the array is evaluated to the number of its elements and *that* is assigned to `$self`. So in the rest of the method there is no object in `$self` but only a number, here `1`.

If you enabled [warnings](https://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) via `use warnings;` on the top of the program, you'd receive

> Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ...

for the line where you attempt to call a method on `$self`, telling you that the expected object (hashref) is in fact a string. This gives you the exact line and an informative, if terse, [diagnostic message](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html).  Without the warnings enabled the code quietly proceeds, but can't do as expected.

The moral:   *Please always have `use warnings` (and `use strict`) at the beginning*

The fix is to make it a "list assignment" -- assign in the list "context"

```
my ($self) = @_;
```

where the list context is imposed on the assignment operator `=` by `(...)` on the left hand side. Now elements in the array `@_` are assigned to variables listed in `()`, one for one. There is just one variable on the LHS here (`$self`) so the first element of `@_` is assigned to it and the rest, if there were any, discarded.

Or, assign a single element of `@_` to `$self` in a scalar assignment. 
In object oriented code this is often done using [shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), so to also remove the object from the argument list for later convenience

```
my $self = shift;
```

where `shift` in a subroutine by default works on `@_`.

See [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context) and [Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54564428/4653379).

I'd recommend to always write a [class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) in its own `.pm` file, which is then `use`d in a program. For error handling in packages see [Carp](https://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126365/whats-the-difference-between-my-variablename-and-my-variablename-in-perl