# Get the value of 2nd index by mapping 1st index through Hash of Arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a Perl file code state.pl where I am trying to retrieve full name of State based on State code from Hash of Arrays. Following is the code:

```
my $all_state_details = {
          IN => [
                  [
                    "AP",
                    "Andhra Pradesh"
                  ],
                  [
                    "AN",
                    "Andaman and Nicobar Islands"
                  ],
                  [
                    "AR",
                    "Arunachal Pradesh"
                  ],
                ],
        US => [
                  [
                    "AL",
                    "Alabama"
                  ],
                  [
                    "AK",
                    "Alaska"
                  ],
                  [
                    "AS",
                    "American Samoa"
                  ],
                ],
        };

my $state = 'AN';
my $country = 'IN';

my @states = $all_state_details->{$country};
my @state_name = grep { $_->[0] eq $state } @states;
print @state_name;
```

When I run the script, I get the blank output

I want the output as just:

```
Andaman and Nicobar Islands
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@{ ... }` dereference operation is necessary to convert the array reference in `$all_state_details->{$country}` into an array suitable for use with `grep`.

```
print map { $_->[1] } 
     grep { $_->[0] eq $state } @{$all_state_details->{$country}};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I tried this ```my $state_name = map { $_->[1] } grep { $_->[0] eq $state } @{$all_state_details->{$country}}; print $state_name``` but $state_name value is returning 1

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126365/whats-the-difference-between-my-variablename-and-my-variablename-in-perl

Comment: Re "*into an array suitable for use with `grep`*",   Into the individual scalars contained in the array, as suitable for `grep`

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this kind of lookup is with a hash of hashes.

e.g.

```
%all_state_details = (
      IN => {
                "AP" => "Andhra Pradesh",
                "AN" => "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
            },
);
```

Then you just do a direct lookup.

```
print $all_state_details{IN}{AN};
```

Read https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES

HTH